# Verbatim inside def in eplain

Tags: macros, verbatim

How can I use `\verbatim` inside my own `\def` with eplain? The eplain reference suggests to change catcodes to accomplish this, but doesn't provide an example of this.

Crarification: I would like to define `\ttcode` so that when I would use it (`\ttcode{some text which can span several par's}`, it would expand thusly:

```
\bigskip\verbatim some text which can span several par's
|endverbatim\bigskip\noindent
```

Comment: Just so that I understand correctly, the argument of `\ttcode` cannot contain a `{` or a `}` or at least an unbalanced `{` or `}`?

Comment: If it cannot contain "{" or "}", then I guess I'm better off using \verbatim "manually".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question. Here's a revised answer.

```
\def\ttcode{\bigskip\verbatim\ttcodehelper}
\begingroup
\catcode`\{12
\catcode`\}12
\catcode`<1
\catcode`>2
\long\gdef\ttcodehelper{#1}<#1\endverbatim\bigskip\noindent>
\endgroup
asdf
\ttcode{Some text

&$%#||

which can span multiple paragraphs.}
asdf
```

Comment: For some reason, it still gave me the "doesn't match its definition" -error. Is it right to use \endverbatim above, as eplain \verbatim changes the "\"-escape to "|" (if I've understood correctly)?

Comment: @morbusg: The above code preceded by `\input eplain` and followed by `\bye` gives you an error? It compiles just fine for me. And yes, `\endverbatim` is correct. You have to consider the category code of \ and `|` at the time of `\ttcodehelper`'s definition which is when the replacement text gets tokenized.

Comment: @TH: I tried it with a blank new document with just the above, and it compiled for me, too. I must have had some typo somewhere or the order of other definitions mattered (I put the `ttcode` definition right after `\input eplain` this time). Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it somehow possible to use this inside another macro, ie: `\long\def\foo#1{#1} \foo{bar\par\ttcode{baz}}` (it gives: "Use of \ttcodehelper doesn't match its definition.")?

Comment: @morbusg: I don't believe so. There are two problems, one general, one specific. The general problem is that the argument gets tokenized when the macro gets expanded. This is a problem with any macro that changes category codes. The specific problem here is that `\ttcodehelper` is looking for braces with category code 12 to delimit its argument. It's analogous to `\def\foo<#1>{...}`. The argument to `\foo` must appear between `<` and `>`. The only difference here is that the category codes for `{}` and `<>` have been swapped, hence `\long\gdef\ttcodehelper{#1}<...>`.