# Why does TeX Live's pdfTeX's %& parsing override the executable name?

Tags: texlive, pdftex

In testing my answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/verbatim-inside-def-in-eplain), I initially wrote the file

```
%& eplain
% code to answer question here
\bye
```

and compiled with `pdftex e`. Much to my surprise, the penultimate line of output was

```
Output written on e.dvi (1 page, 352 bytes).
```

If I change the first line to `\input eplain` or add the command line argument `-output-format=pdf`, then I get a pdf.

This same behavior can be observed by by starting a LaTeX file with `%& latex` and compiling with either `pdflatex` or `pdftex` so it's unrelated to `eplain`.

Comment: You are doing two different things. Using `\input` simply loads the relevant .tex file, whereas first-line parsing switches engine alias. Remember that almost all of the *tex execuatables are aliases for pdfTeX with the appropriate format. So the first line you are using effectively switch the command line to `eplain`.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I think your description is backward. The name of the executable is used as the name of the format. I didn't realize that there were different `.fmt` files for latex and pdflatex though. It doesn't really seem necessary to have them since one can choose the output format independently of the format file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, because that is what it is supposed to do. the `%&` line allows you to switch to another format than the one matching the executable name, so your line above is exactly as running `eplain e` or `pdftex -fmt eplain e`. Read the first few lines of `pdftex --help`.

Comment: I did read that, actually. The relevant line reads, "If the first line of TEXNAME is %&FMT, and FMT is an existing .fmt file, use it." What I wasn't aware of is that the `.fmt` file dictates the output format since, as I said to Joseph, they can be selected independently.

Comment: The PDF output format has to be explicitly set on the format, or how else do you thing pdf(latex)tex would default to PDF, while latex defaults to dvi. I myself don't even like the different executable per format, this what command line switches are for, but this is not what TeX world is accustomed to.

Comment: @Khaled Hosny: If that were true, then -output-format=pdf would not work with explicit formats. For example, there is no pdfeplain.fmt, yet as I mentioned, I can get pdf files by passing the command line argument while using the eplain.fmt.

Comment: @Khaled Hosny: In fact, just setting `\pdfoutput=1` is sufficient to get pdf output. I had assumed (incorrectly) that that's essentially what pdftex would do by default I didn't expect the format files to be setting that at all.

Comment: I think you are confusing things up (or may be I'm saying it in a confusing way), I'm not saying the only way to get PDF output is to set it in the format; I'm saying it is the only way to get it *by default*, this does not mean you can not override it by command line switches or TeX primitives.

Comment: @Khaled: Sorry, didn't see this until just now. I think we're talking at cross purposes. You're saying that this is the only way to do something with what we have. I was saying that there's a simple way this _could_ have been implemented, namely a single format file for LaTeX with pdflatex just defaulting to `\pdfoutput=1` and latex just defaulting to `\pdfoutput=0`. Anyway, all resolved now, thanks.